# give equal space between ImageViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

i am trying to add some social images in my app about me screen but i am facing a problem of giving equal spaces between imageviews.

my images looks like this:

[image: see screenshot]

but i want to make them look like this:

[image: see screenshot]

my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/about_screen" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSocialMediaContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottum_padding" >

        <!-- Facebook -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <!-- Twitter -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

        <!-- Google+ -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/google" />

        <!-- Linkedin -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/linkedin" />

        <!-- Blog -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/blog" />

        <!-- Youtube -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/youtube" />

        <!-- Email -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/mail" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set margin left in each of your imageviews

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go, modify the code accordingly,  learn about `android:layout_weight` it is usefull in such situations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

set layout_margin property of imageview to give space between thos image view.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<Space/>` element in your Linearlayout between the imageviews to add equal space. You can assign the width using the weight property of LinearLayouts to get equally spaced icons in all different form factors.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llSocialMediaContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/bottum_padding" >

        <!-- Facebook -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <!-- Twitter -->

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/social"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/social"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />
```

For each of the ImageViews. This should give them equal width of the total linearlayout width. I'm not sure if this will stretch your images or not, if it does you might need to set the scale type.