# Android LinearLayout: putting some object with equal space

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I need to put some ImageButton with equal space in layout(something like the picture I attached). 
I checked a lot of similar posts like:

[Android: How to make all elements inside LinearLayout same size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177020/android-how-to-make-all-elements-inside-linearlayout-same-size)

[give equal space between ImageViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27268144/give-equal-space-between-imageviews)

[What is android:weightSum in android, and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452741/what-is-androidweightsum-in-android-and-how-does-it-work)

However they didn't help me.
Using margin and padding didn't solve my problem, because I want to have equal space around ImageButton. It is important for me to keep the space equal **in any device**. Also I want to set size to my ImageButton. It's a rounded image so the height and width of image should be equal . When I use weightsum, I can't set arbitrary width as layout_width for ImageButton.

Thanks for helping me.

P.S. This is not duplicate post. In the first link which i brought, it is not possible to set equal space. It just put objects next to each other.

This is a layout with 2 ImageButton with arbitrary size:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialdesign.activity.HomeFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"    
android:background="@drawable/background_home">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/log_guid_image_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/log_guid_image_height"
    android:onClick="onLastClick"
    android:id="@+id/btn_menu_last"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_last" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="@dimen/log_guid_image_height"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/log_guid_image_height"
    android:onClick="onAddClick"
    android:id="@+id/btn_menu_add_records"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_add_records" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I added android:layout_weight="1" to each ImageButton, and set android:layout_width="0px" and it gave me this:

[image]

The problem is that how I can add equal space around ImageButton and gave arbitrary size to them!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: How to make all elements inside LinearLayout same size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177020/android-how-to-make-all-elements-inside-linearlayout-same-size); You didn't read this post. [Its accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1177076/3501958) isn't about using margin or padding.

Comment: NOOO, I checked that post too. Plz first read question carefully then post comment. I said I need to set arbitrary width and height to ImageButton.

Comment: then post your xml layout that you have tried

Comment: @Taher I can't get your point... Please post your code as Boss said.

Comment: @Taher I got your point, perhaps. I posted an answer. If it may help you.

Comment: @Taher Did your problem cleared? If you were disgusted with my comment (possible duplicate), please excuse me.

Comment: Your welcome. 
No, I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TableLayout`as below:

```
 <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

You can you use a inner `LinearLayout` at the place of `ImageButton` to customize your `ImageButton` position.

Comment: No, It does not add enough space between ImageButtons.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:-

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_home"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_menu_last"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:onClick="onLastClick"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_last" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_menu_add_records"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:onClick="onAddClick"
        android:src="@drawable/menu_add_records" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just nest `LinearLayouts` like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Put `ImageButtons` inside each `LinearLayouts`.

Using `LinearLayout` and getting equal space is essentially the same idea as the past [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177020/android-how-to-make-all-elements-inside-linearlayout-same-size) you read.

And inside these equal spaced cells, you can put `ImageButtons` with **layout_gravity="center"** (or **gravity="center"** with `LinearLayout` as shown abobe).

Answer (score 0):

I think for this problem you need use a `GridView` and specify `columnWidth` option.

Comment: I don't want to use fixed sizes.

Comment: @Taher GridView align items dynamicaly related to you specified settings.

Comment: I can use two column GridView but, the problem is that the imageButton inside each column doesn't align center, so I have to use padding!!! I checked some questions but they didn't solve my problem too.